# Classical Mechanics & Coordinates

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, variational-principle

1. What is the meaning [generalised coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_coordinates) in Classical Mechanics?
2. How is [Lagrangian formalism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) different from [Hamiltonian formalism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics)?
3. How are they related to [Hamilton's Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%27s_principle)?
4. How are they related to [Euler-Lagrange equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation)?

Comment: These are three separate and very general questions, each worth a discussion on their own.

Comment: You'll need to read some books to answer all these questions.

Comment: A summary/sort of what we are trying to do will help before reading the book.

Comment: 1. a good mathematical description of a physical system, 2. velocities are replaced by momenta, 3. lets you find equations of motion in 2.'s, 4. is the application of 3....

Answer (score 1):

I wll answer the first question to get the ball rolling.

Consider tracking a particle that is constrained on a 2D path. Can can choose to keep track of the $x$, $y$ coordinates separately (2 dof system) and include a constraint equation to keep the particle on the path.

Or

You can use a generalized coordinate which might be the distance along the path, or the polar angle, or whatever else makes sense to you and keeps the particle on the path with only 1 coordinate specification. Thus no need for an additional constraint equation.

That is the reason people use generalized coordinates, to reduce the system degrees of freedom acording to the constraints.